# Angular 2 http post request is not being called out

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am using angular 2 to make a get request and a post request. My get request works fine, but for my post, **I do not see the request is made** when checking my Firebug Net panel.

The code methods look like follows. I also have subscribe methods invoking them from a component class.

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions,  Jsonp, URLSearchParams} from "angular2/http";
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

 @Injectable()
export class MyService{
    constructor (private _http: Http){}  


testPost(){      

    var json = JSON.stringify({"userId": 111, "givenName": "CZ"});
    var body = "json="+json;
    var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post("http://mylocal.post.url", body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);

}

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    alert("test whether this method is reached");

    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
    alert("test whether this method is reached");

    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }     

 //testGet method is running well
testGet(link:string){

    return this._http.get(link)
    .map(res => res);

}     
}
```

my subscribing method onTestPost(), which is assigned to a button on the page.

```
onTestPost(){
    this.myService.testPost()
    .subscribe(
        data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("Finished")            
        );
}
```

I put an alert statement at the beginning of two helper methods. None of the alerts is reached. And I don't see any request called to the my local post url when debugging with Firebug.

While my testGet method works correctly, I just don't know what is missing for the testPost.

Comment: The code looks okay, most likely you didn't really subscribed properly.

Comment: Just in case, make sure something like a mock backend is not catching the request.

Answer (score 11):

I think your subscribe methods are the issue here. Please make sure `subscribe` is called.

> "This observable is cold which means the request won't go out until
>   something subscribes to the observable."

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I have added my subscribing method. However, I believe my service method testPost() has been invoked. I put on alert statement. It demonstrated the codes before the return statement are run through.

Comment: I wish I saw this reply earlier. have wasted whole day digging out issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
testPost() : Observable <Response> //import{Response} from '@angular/http'
{      
var json = JSON.stringify({"userId": 111, "givenName": "CZ"});
var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http.post("http://mylocal.post.url/api",JSON.stringify(json), options)
    .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```